# ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python

I installed v4l2py with pip3. I'm using Bullseye.
At execution time, v4l2py issued the error message (see title).
Some DuckDuckGo research told me that recent changes in C bindings in numpy 1.20 created the problem.

Upgrading numpy may create problems with installed applications.
Would it be better to downgrade v4l2py?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering to my own question.
numpy >=1.20 is not available from Bullseye repository.
So I decided to install it from pypi through pip3.
It installed 1.22.1 but pip3 reported it was not able to remove 1.19.5.
And then numpy reported "libcblas.3 not found".
Seemed to me that leaving 2 versions may cause confusion so I did:

- removed numpy 1.22.1 through pip3
- removed python3-numpy 1.19.5 through apt. It has consequences: apt report that 14 packages would be removed (including python2.7, jupyter and ruby).
- Then I had to install libatlas-base-dev (it replace libcblas-dev).
- And finally, apt autoremove removed 152 packages.
  It's surprising that so many packages are affected.

A change in C bindings of Numpy created an avalanche.

My RPi seems to work normally but I'm watching for surprises.

I will report if I find problems.